# How to sort results by column in associated table in Grails?

Tags: sorting, grails, grails-orm

I have two domain classes with a simple one to many relationship (a Gift can have many GiftInstance), as below.  I wish to retrieve all GiftInstances for a given user (and potentially other criteria), but sort the results based on the 'expired' attribute of Gift associated with each GiftInstance.  How would I accomplish this?  I would prefer to stay within the confines of Grails (dynamic finder, Criteria, etc) not have to execute raw SQL

```
class Gift {

    String name;
    String description;
    Date expires;
}

class GiftInstance {

    static belongsTo = [gift: Gift]
    User user;
    ... other fields ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this via [mapping in your domain class](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#defaultSortOrder) with two ways.

either set the sort and the order in Gift class like this:

```
class Gift {

    String name;
    String description;
    Date expires;

    static hasMany = [giftInstances: GiftInstance]

    static mapping = {
        giftInstances sort: "expired"
    }

}
```

or in your GiftInstance domain class.

```
class GiftInstance {

    static belongsTo = [gift: Gift]
    User user
    boolean expired

    static mapping = {
        sort: "expired"
    }
}
```

yes, you can also set the order.

Comment: I don't think this answers my question.  The query I want for giftInstance is by user, which spans many different Gifts, so I'm not interested in just ordering all the instances for a particular gift.  And there is no 'expired' boolean on my GiftInstance, why did you add it?

Comment: hi, i'm sorry. that was due misreading your question. i read it as "GiftInstance" has an "expired" property whereas "Gift" has "expires". nonetheless, this mapping sets that sorting mode and ordering default in the queries you use.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a named query in GiftInstance

```
class GiftInstance {

    static namedQueries = {
      giftInstanceByUser {  user ->
          eq 'user', user

          order 'gift.expires', 'asc'
      }
    }
}
```